# Bullets only killing first enemy

Tags: c++, 2d-games

I'm making a 2D game in c++ and am trying to shoot enemies. When a bullet collides with the first enemy rendered then the enemy is killed fine, and it is removed from the `enemys` vector. However after the first enemy has been killed, other enemies no longer die.

This is where the check is carried out in the update function.

```
size = enemys.size();
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        double x = enemys[i].getEnemyX();
        double y = enemys[i].getEnemyY();
        bool isShot = enemyShot(x,y);
        if(isShot == true){
            enemys.erase(enemys.begin()+i);
            size = size - 1;
        }
    }
```

This is the enemyShot function.

```
bool GameActivity::enemyShot(double enemyX, double enemyY)
{
int size = bullets.size();
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    double x = bullets[i].getX();
    double y = bullets[i].getY();
    if (x >= enemyX-5.0 && x <= enemyX+5.0 && y >= enemyY-5.0 &&  y <= enemyY + 5.0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop that erases an enemy from its list always will skip the enemy *after* the one you removed.

Comment: shouldn't it erase every other enemy then instead of just one?

Comment: `size = size - 1;` => `--size,--i;` BTW: If the bullets are round, try this: `(x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2)<size*size`. If they are squares, this: `(fabs(x1-x2)<size && fabs(y1-y2)<size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your vector of enemies is updated after each erasure - thus, the current index is no longer correct.
A better way to iterate the enemys vector is to start from the end of the enemys vector. That way, when you erase an element, the index is still correct:

```
for (size_t i = enemys.end (); i> 0; --i) {
    double x = enemys[i].getEnemyX();
    double y = enemys[i].getEnemyY();
    bool isShot = enemyShot(x,y);
    if(isShot == true){
        enemys.erase(enemys.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new so I can't fix the wrong formatting of the code posted

Comment: what type do you make i = enemys.end() in the for loop?

Comment: i wrote size_t since this is the type returned by std::Vector::Size (), it's more correct than int. But you can use int as well